# Getting UITextfield value in KIF Framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, kif, kif-framework

I had integrated KIF Framework in project for testing purpose, but I'm not able to get the value of the textField?

In case i have to wait until I got response form server. I used 
 `[tester waitForAnimationsToFinish];`
but its going to next step so I want to check that result textfield value.